# Powershell : Excel data reading issue

Tags: excel, powershell, row

I have an issue with a powershell script which is supposed to read data into an excel file (.csv)

My excel content

| Request | Request Name |
| --- | --- |
| Service 1 | SA1 |
| Service 2 | SA2 |
| Service 3 | SA3 |

What I need is to retrieve the content of the second column with the value present in the first column

If i select "Service 1" , get the value SA1

Thanks in advance for your help

Regards

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: `$csv = import-csv c:\temp.csv; $csv | ? Request -match "Service 1"`

Comment: I just got the first column items for the moment 

$Header = 'Request'
$ReqList = Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path "C:\Scripts\Templates.csv" | select -ExpandProperty $Header 

Im now searching for a solution to get the value of the related row in the second column when i choose one item from the first

Comment: The final result i expect is :
The first column is displayed in a combobox 
For example If a user select "Service 1", the returned result should be "SA1"

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you can do the following:

```
$RequestValue = 'Service 2'
(Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path "C:\Scripts\Templates.csv" |
    Where Request -eq $RequestValue).'Request Name'
```

Having a variable `$RequestValue` is not necessary, but this is simulating a scenario where you retrieve that value elsewhere in your code. You could use `Where Request -eq 'Service 2'` instead.

`Where` is an alias for [Where-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.1). The syntax `where property operator value` is used here. The row that meets the criterion property `Request` has a value of `$RequestValue` is selected.

Using [Member Access Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#member-access-operator-) (`.propertyName`), you can retrieve the value of the `Request Name` property. Since the property name contains a space, you will need to surround it in quotes so it is parsed correctly.